# Solve system $x^2+y^2=\frac{2xy}{z}$; $y^2+z^2=\frac{2yz}{x}$; $x^2+z^2=\frac{2xz}{y}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, contest-math

A problem from the National Mathematical Olympiad in Bulgaria:

> Solve the system:
>
> $$\begin{aligned} x^2+y^2 &= \dfrac{2xy}{z} \\ y^2+z^2 &= \dfrac{2yz}{x} \\ x^2+z^2 &= \dfrac{2xz}{y} \end{aligned}$$

As always: $$\begin{array}{|l} x \ne 0 \\ y \ne 0 \\ z \ne 0 \end{array}$$
Now I am trying to see what I can do to simplify and solve the system. I tried to choose two of the equations and eliminate a variable, but I didn't succeed.

This is a problem from a national olympiad so it must have something tricky that I haven't seen. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: If you multiply the equations by $z^2, x^2, y^2$ respectively, you get $$ z^2(x^2 + y^2) = x^2(y^2 + z^2) = y^2(z^2 + x^2) = 2xyz $$. You can start eliminating using this. For instance, the first three equalities give $x^2 y^2 = y^2 z^2 = z^2 x^2$...

Comment: Hint: Multiply the equation through by $z^2,x^2$ and $y^2$ respectively. Now subtract pairs of equations.

Comment: Okay. I got: $\begin{array}{|l} x^2z^2+y^2z^2=2xyz \\ y^2x^2+z^2x^2=2xyz \\ x^2y^2+z^2y^2=2xyz\end{array}$. I am not sure I understand what do you next.

Comment: Try to subtract the second equation from the first and so on.

Comment: I really don't understand how to solve the system (after multiplying by $z^2,x^2$ and $y^2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given,
$$ x^2+y^2 = \dfrac{2xy}{z} \tag 1$$
$$y^2+z^2 = \dfrac{2yz}{x} \tag 2$$
$$ x^2+z^2 = \dfrac{2xz}{y} \tag 3$$

Take (1)-(2) and (3)-(2) to get

$$(x^2-z^2)(xz-2y) = 0$$
$$(x^2-y^2)(xy-2z) = 0$$

So, there are four cases to examine from the factor combinations of the two equations above:

**Case 1**) $x^2-z^2=0$ and $x^2-y^2=0$. Plug $x^2=y^2$ into (1),

$$2x(xz-y)=0\implies xz=y\implies z=\pm1$$

which leads to the solutions $(1,1,1),(1,-1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1)$.

**Case 2**) $xz-2y=0$ and $xy-2z =0$, which leads to $x^2=4$. Plug it and $xy=2z$ into (1) to get

$$4+y^2 = 4\implies y=0$$

Since $y\ne0$, there are no solutions.

**Case 3**) $x^2-z^2=0$ and $xy-2z=0$. Then, $x^2=z^2=\frac14x^2y^2\implies y^2=4$. Plus it and $xy=2z$ into (1)

$$x^2+4 = 4\implies x=0$$

Since $x\ne 0$, there are no solutions.

**Case 4**) $x^2-y^2=0$ and $xz-2y=0$. There are no solutions based on similar argument in Case 3).

Thus, the valid solutions only come from Case 1), i.e. $(1,1,1),(1,-1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x,y,z > 0$ . WLOG assume further that : $x \ge y \ge z$. Then : $\dfrac{1}{z} = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2xy} \ge 1 \implies z \le 1$. By the same argument, we have: $x \le 1, y \le 1$. Thus : $x^2 \le x , y^2 \le y, z^2 \le z$ and $\dfrac{2xy}{z}= x^2 + y^2 \le x+y \implies \dfrac{2}{z} \le \dfrac{x+y}{xy} = \dfrac{1}{x} +  \dfrac{1}{y} $. But $ x \ge y \ge z \implies \dfrac{1}{z} \ge \dfrac{1}{y} \ge \dfrac{1}{x} \implies \dfrac{2}{z} \ge \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{y} \implies \dfrac{1}{z} = \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{1}{y} \implies x = y= z = 1$.

Note: if say $x > 0, y < 0, z < 0$ we set $y’ = -y, z’ = -z$ then we are back to all positive solutions $(x,y’,z’)$. This covers the case OP mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: Isn't $(-1;1;-1)$ a solution? Also I see $(-1;-1;1)$ is a solution.

Comment: Sure. You can cover the case you mentioned . My answer treats the main case of positive $x,y,z$ as it uses inequalities to force $x = y = z = 1$.

Comment: How can I cover all the cases?

Comment: Please see my edit.